# Localization in Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, localization

I'm currently experiementing the localization in **Xamarin.IOS**. I managed to get the localization work but only based on the system language. Here's my example:

`someLabel.Text = NSBundle.MainBundle.GetLocalizedString ("Hello");`

The question is how can I change the Localization within the App through code? Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve localization, you can create the .lproj folder under the Resources file, and then select localization in Xcode to select the language, and the corresponding strings will be generated in Visual Studio accordingly. When using NSBundle.MainBundle.GetLocalizedString ("Yes"); please make sure that the Localizable.strings file exists in your .lproj folder.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This is what I've tried: I created the ```.lproj``` folders under the Resources file in **Visual Studio** and went into **Xcode** to create a ```.strings``` file. I then **localized** it with multiple languages and added the strings I need. When getting back to **Visual Studio**, the files are generated. However, the ```NSBundle.MainBundle.GetLocalizedString()```still does not work, giving me the input parameter as output.

Comment: You can select the Localization option in Xcode and the corresponding file will be created automatically

Comment: Yes, I did select the **Localization** option in **Xcode** and the corresponding files are generated.

Comment: Did you create the Base.lproj folder and put the Main.storyboard file in it according to the official documentation, and make sure that your lproj folder has Localizable.strings and must be called by this name

Comment: When the phone system language changes, it will automatically go to the .lproj file to find the corresponding .strings